# Possible conflict between BibLaTeX and navigator packages

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber

I'm having trouble using both the `biblatex` package (to manage the bibliography) and the `navigator` package (to embed a file into the PDF). Here is a minimum example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{navigator}

\addbibresource{latextest.bib}

% Just need some file here
\embeddedfile{Test}[Test.txt]{latextest.bib}

\begin{document}

Test

Test \cite{ctan}

Test

\printbibliography

\finishpdffile

\end{document}
```

Here are the contents of latextest.bib:

```
@online{ctan,
    title = "The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network",
    url = "https://ctan.org/"
}
```

The log file shows several errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \bibname 

l.11 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \begin{document}

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Too many }'s.
<argument> ...cs \bibname {\abx@str @bibliography}

l.11 \begin{document}

You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.

! Too many }'s.
<argument> \letcs \refname {\abx@str @references}

l.11 \begin{document}

You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \biblistname 

l.11 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Too many }'s.
<argument> ... \biblistname {\abx@str @shorthands}

l.11 \begin{document}

You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
```

If the bibliography-related commands (`\usepackage{biblatex}`, `\addbibresource`, `\cite`, and `\printbibliography`) are commented out then compilation is successful. Similarly, if the commands related to embedding the file (`\usepackage{navigator}`, `\embeddedfile`, and `\finishpdffile`) are commented out, then compilation is also successful.

This happens with both MiKTeX 2.9.7216-x64 (re-installed yesterday and all packages up-to-date) and TeX Live 2017.20180305-1 running on Ubuntu. I'm compiling with XeTeX and Biber.

I'd appreciate any fixes or suggestions on how to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed a fundamental incompatibility between `navigator` and `biblatex` (or to be more precise a fundamental incompatibility between the TeX programming toolboxes the two use, namely `texapi` and `etoolbox`).

If you exchange the loading order of the two packages in the minimal example to

```
\usepackage{navigator}
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

you'll get the following error

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"

! LaTeX Error: Command \letcs already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

This suggests that `navigator` or a package that is loaded by `navigator` defines the command `\letcs` that is also defined by `etoolbox` (which is needed by `biblatex`).

A bit of digging shows that `texapi`, which is loaded by `navigator`, has

```
\long\pdef\letcs#1{\expandafter\let  \csname#1\endcsname}
```

whereas `etoolbox` has

```
\newrobustcmd{\letcs}[2]{%
  \ifcsdef{#2}
    {\expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname#2\endcsname}
    {\undef#1}}
```

Unfortunately, these two definitions have the exact opposite 'syntax'. `texapi`'s version is used as

```
\letcs{foo}\bar
```

while `etoolbox` uses its version as

```
\letcs\foo{bar}
```

Since the command is ubiquitous in both `navigator` and `biblatex` this name clash makes the packages pretty much incompatible. If you want to make the two packages work together you have to save and restore the correct version of `\letcs` as needed by the commands used.

In the MWE below things are set up so that the working definition of `\letcs` throughout the document is the one from `etoolbox`. This means that for every `navigator` command we need to locally reset `\letcs` to its `texapi` definition.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{navigator}
\let\navletcs\letcs
\let\letcs\relax
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{latextest.bib}
@online{ctan,
    title = "The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network",
    url = "https://ctan.org/"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{latextest.bib}

\begingroup
\let\letcs\navletcs
\embeddedfile{Test}[Test.txt]{latextest.bib}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
Test

Test \cite{ctan}

Test

\printbibliography

\begingroup
\let\letcs\navletcs
\finishpdffile
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ingenious solution, thank you for the thorough explanation!