# yax incompatible with biblatex: Undefined control sequence

Tags: biblatex, templates

While trying to use [`yax`](https://ctan.org/pkg/yax?lang=en) in my thesis, I discovered that it was incompatible with `biblatex` in the same way as described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511621/possible-conflict-between-biblatex-and-navigator-packages). I tried to apply the workaround described in [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511650/142924) to that question, and it worked with `article` document class, but not with [the Master/PhD thesis template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) I'm using.

This is the minimal example (it compiles if I change the document class to `article`):

```
\documentclass[english]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{yax}

\let\navletcs\letcs
\let\letcs\relax
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}
    It is sometimes really hard to get TeX to work.
\end{document}
```

The first error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \letcs \blx@backrefsetstyle 
                                       {blx@opt@backrefsetstyle@setonly}
l.13363 ...conds=false,julian=false,labeltime=24h}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not actually `biblatex` that is incompatible with `yax`, it's `etoolbox`. (`biblatex` loads and uses `etoolbox` for *many* things. And it's not actually `yax`, it's `texapi`, which is loaded by `yax`.)

`MastersDoctoralThesis` also loads `etoolbox`, so when you say

```
\documentclass[english]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage{yax}

\let\navletcs\letcs
\let\letcs\relax
```

`etoolbox` has already been loaded by `MastersDoctoralThesis` and `yax` has already overwritten its `\letcs`.

The following

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

will *not* load `etoolbox` again, because LaTeX loads packages only once. So `etoolbox` will not overwrite the definitions from `yax`.

The error can be avoided by making sure `yax` is really loaded before `etoolbox`. We also save the definitions of `\letcs` to be able to switch between them later.

```
\RequirePackage{yax}
\let\texapiletcs\letcs
\let\letcs\relax
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\let\etoolboxletcs\letcs
\documentclass[english]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}
    It is sometimes really hard to get TeX to work.
\end{document}
```

---

Note that uses of commands defined by `yax` may break in the document unless you switch to `texapi`'s definition of `\letcs` and that commands defined by `biblatex`/`etoolbox` may break if you don't switch back quickly enough.

Avoiding groups (which may have undesirable side effects) this can be done roughly as follows

```
\let\letcs\texapiletcs % switch to texapi definition
... do stuff with yax ...
\let\letcs\etoolboxletcs % go back to etoolbox definition
```

If at all possible I recommend you look for an alternative to `yax`. I'm also not too fond of `MastersDoctoralThesis` (it appears to me that it usually causes more trouble for people than necessary), so if you still have a chance to switch to a more standard document class, that's something you may seriously want to consider.

Comment: Thanks you! The solution doesn't fully work in my case though. I want to define a bunch of `yax` values (`\setparameter`) and then use them throughout the text with `\usevalue`. If I wrap a definition and a usage in the same `\begingroup \let\letcs\navletcs \endgroup` it works, but with separate groups it doesn't (the value doesn't show up). Is there a workaround for this? On a related note, what would you suggest as alternatives to `yax` and to the thesis template?

Comment: @SergeiTikhomirov Check out the update, please. I don't know what you need `yax` for, so I can't suggest a good alternative (I hadn't heard of `yax` until today). An alternative for the thesis template is not to use a template at all and to start from one of the standard classes (probably `report` or `book` for a thesis) one of the KOMA-Script classes (`scrreprt`, `scrbook`) or `memoir`.

Comment: @sergei https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports